# My function won't read the high and low weather data from my string list

Tags: python

I have to code a function that reads the specific (third and fourth columns of data) data positions where the temperature data is and find/print the high and low temperatures of the year.  My data is weather dates and they are already split into separate lists for each day of the year. It's supposed to read my data file and populate a list with the data, and then it will return the list.
I've tried using if functions inside of loops.

...

```
##This function will return the populated list
##High and Low temperatures for each day in the window.
def highLow():
    highest = 0
    lowest = 200
    file = open("KMDW.csv","r")
    sheet = file.readline()
    for i in file:
        if i > highest:
            highest = i
        if i < lowest:
            lowest = i
    answer = [highest,lowest]
    return answer
    print(answer)
highLow()
```

> File "C:\Users\vegit\OneDrive\Documents\CSI class
>   PATANKAR\Python\Part1QuarterProject.py", line 25, in highLow
>       if i > highest: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing an integer (`int`) to a string (`str`) in the comparison. More specifically, the `for i in file` sets `i` to a `str` for every line. An potential fix would be to cast the temperature into an `int` like this:

```
for line in file:
    temperature = int( line.split( ',' )[2] )
    if temperature > highest:
        highest = temperature
    if temperature < lowest:
        lowest = temperature
```

NOTE: I made some edits based on information about the problem that was later revealed in the comments by OP... Basically, OP has a CSV file with multiple items per line separated by commas. The goal is to evaluate the third (fourth?) column against against the highest and lowest temperatures. I added in an additional line that splits the line (via `str.split()`) by commas and select the third column (via the `[2]` index). This newly extracted value is cast into an integer (via the `int()` notation) and compared against the upper and lower limits.

Comment: The solution gave me this error: "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '7/1/2014,76,68,84,67,84,49,103,1982,1956,0.04,0.11,1.23\n'"

Comment: You should edit your original question to include a sample of a few lines in your `KMDW.csv` file as well as the expected behavior/output. I modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform string `i` into `int` or `float` (number type) for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use sheet rather using file,

```
for i in sheet:
    if i > highest:
        highest = i
    if i < lowest:
        lowest = i
```